# adding computed value to observable array in model declaration

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

i have view model with observableArray()

```
var userTaskMyViewModel = {
    userTaskMyDetailsDTO: ko.observableArray() 
};
```

once i get the data i try to add a computed function using

```
  $.each(userTaskMyViewModel.userTaskMyDetailsDTO(), function (index, userTask) {

                userTask.TaskCss = ko.computed(function () {
                    var result = "item-green";
                    if (userTask.Percent == 0)
                        result = "item-red";

                    return result;
                });
```

**Problem is i have already applied the bindings before i get the data** , since i need to get data multiple times from server and add to this model.

**since i have data-bind with TaskCss in my view it errors saying not defined.** i think i need to declare this when i declare my ko model
    **how do i do this? adding computed value to observable array in model declaration.**

I use this call to get the data and populate model.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/api/task/gettasklist",
        type: "get",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: { pageId: pageNumber }
    }).done(function (data) {
        if (data.length > 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                userTaskMyViewModel.userTaskMyDetailsDTO.push(data[i]);
            }
```

Comment: How are you getting the data and adding observables to the observable array? The computed has to be added to each item before it is added to the array.

Comment: @AnthonyChu i just updated the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `TaskCss` to the item before pushing it onto the observable array...

```
function addTaskCss (userTask) {
    userTask.TaskCss = ko.computed(function () {
        return (userTask.Percent === 0) ? "item-red" : "item-green";
    });
}

// ...

$.ajax(/* ... */).done(function (data) {
        if (data.length > 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                addTaskCss(data[i]);
                userTaskMyViewModel.userTaskMyDetailsDTO.push(data[i]);
            }
```

If the ajax call is returning a lot of items, consider pushing to the underlying array and notify subscribers once as this is more efficient...

```
$.ajax(/* ... */).done(function (data) {
    var userTaskMyDetailArray = userTaskMyViewModel.userTaskMyDetailsDTO();
    if (data.length > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            addTaskCss(data[i]);
            userTaskMyDetailArray.push(data[i]);
        }
        userTaskMyViewModel.userTaskMyDetailsDTO.valueHasMutated();
```

More information about this technique here... http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/04/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha.html